# where T : class to VB

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm trying to convert this:

```
public virtual IDbSet DbSet() where T : class
```

to this

```
Public Overridable Function DbSet() As IDbSet(Of T As Class)
```

but it doesn't compile. ')' Expected at As (in "As Class")

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

I'm trying to get EF Code First working in VB.

Comment: And what error message might you be receiving?

Comment: Neither of those is actually a generic method...

Comment: @BryanCrosby sorry I knew I forgot something. Edited the post.

Comment: @JonSkeet I never said they are generic methods...

Comment: @ton.yeung the `where T : class` syntax is used as a constraint on a generic parameter.  Because this constraint is on a method, the method must be generic.

Comment: @ton.yeung: As cadrell0 says, constraints are placed on generic member declarations. So basically, your C# code wasn't valid to start with...

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah, I'll take your word for it. I'm copying this code from a tutorial, so I'm not really sure how valid/invalid the code is. My main objective right now is to just get the project compiled. As for why I don't just compile it in C#, because my company doesn't allow C# T.T

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct syntax is:

```
public virtual IDbSet<T> DbSet() where T : class
```

and

```
Public Overridable Function DbSet(Of T As Class)() As IDbSet(Of T)
```

Comment: That's a lot of parentheses - I wonder what happens if you have a generic VB lambda method invocation that involves array indexers. Why does VB love the paren so?

Comment: Given its great age, it is a language that speaks with a lisp.